# Always ask password on local file when modified file when ran docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, docker, passenger, dockerfile

I'm newbie in `docker`. And i tried to create a `Dockerfile` to run a website was written by`rails`, `postgresql` on `apache+passenger`.

But when i `run` `Dockerfile`, it run successfully, but it had a problem with `permission denied`. I found problem that folder web must belongs to `apache` user. Then i tried to change `apache` user to source web (on container). And it run ok.

But every time i modified a file on local. It always ask password when i saved this file.

And i checked `permission` `source` on local. It changed all role to weird role.

How can i solved this problem ?

This is my  [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/khanhpham1990/6ab2b8d379bc1c6dd2c2ffbb5b12deaf).
And i used two commands to run.

```
docker build -t wics .
docker run -v /home/khanhpn/Project/wics:/home/abc -p 80:80 -it wics /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a mount of time, i found a solution to solve this problem.

I just add this line in `Dockerfile`, the problem was solved.

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 apache
```